# reg expression matching extra characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a very simple regular expression.. but which is it always returning true when I add an extra character in the end?

This is correct:

```
'sydt1sn_z1c1' -match "([a-zA-Z]{3}t[1|2][a-zA-Z]{2}_([a-zA-Z][0-9]){2})"
True
```

---

This is also matches. I don't want it too though.

```
 'sydt1sn_z1c1n' -match "([a-zA-Z]{3}t[1|2][a-zA-Z]{2}_([a-zA-Z][0-9]){2})"
True
```

Comment: `'sydt1sn_z1c1n'` returns true since it matches the first part of the string. see vks answer to use anchors so that it captures only matches for the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ^([a-zA-Z]{3}t[1|2][a-zA-Z]{2}_([a-zA-Z][0-9]){2})$
```

Just add anchors.
`^` matches the beginning of the line. 
`$` matches the end of the line.

Since you have `$` it will not match strings with extra characters.

Comment: or you could use word boundaries. One more thing is, you need to remove `|` which was present inside the character class.

Comment: @AvinashRaj ohhhh thanx for that.actually i used OP's regex.Didnt check it

Answer (score 0):

Also you can simplify your expression:

```
\b([a-z]{3}t[1|2][a-z]{2}_([a-z][0-9]){2})\b
```

-match operator is case insensitive

Or if you want validate the entire string:

```
\A([a-z]{3}t[1|2][a-z]{2}_([a-z][0-9]){2})\z
```